# Non-blocking Updatable Priority Queue

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, queue, priority-queue

It is common knowledge to use a heap to implement a priority queue and use a lookup hash table to support priority update.

In parallel settings, the heap-based implementation of a PQ requires a lock on every operation.

If the following operations of a non-blocking PQ are required:

- Pop: pops the head item of the PQ
- Peek: returns the pointer of the head item of the PQ
- Update: updates an item with a given priority

How to implement a non-blocking updatable priority queue?

Literature always avoids the Update operation and only discusses the Push and Pop operation, eg:

- Lindén, Jonatan, and Bengt Jonsson. "A skiplist-based concurrent priority queue with minimal memory contention." International Conference On Principles Of Distributed Systems. Springer, Cham, 2013.
- Shavit, Nir, and Itay Lotan. "Skiplist-based concurrent priority queues." Proceedings 14th International Parallel and Distributed Processing Symposium. IPDPS 2000. IEEE, 2000.
- Dragicevic, Kristijan, and Daniel Bauer. "A survey of concurrent priority queue algorithms." 2008 IEEE International Symposium on Parallel and Distributed Processing. IEEE, 2008.

Comment: What is the aim of this queue? Does all the thread require to be able to read every thing in the queue?

Comment: @TUIlover Task scheduling. Say each task has a priority and the priority can be updated in anytime(e.g. run immediately).

Comment: okay, so you want all operation to be lockless? Or just the majority of them?

Comment: @TUIlover I imagine Len and Peek can be easily implemented by atomic operation. However, the most important operations are Push Pop and Update seems unclear, literature has solutions for Push and Pop only, but not include for Update. Update is critical in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry if I appear annoying, but your question really intrigue me. What do you exactly mean by : "updates an item with a given priority" ? What is the priority policy you want to implement?

Comment: @TUIlover Well. Say execution time of a task. A task was scheduled 3 hours later. However, at some point (maybe 2 hours later), the task needs to be rescheduled to be executed immediately or be delayed about 2 more hours. Note that during all periods, there may have other tasks to be enqueued to the priority queue. So the Update operation means: 1. lookup a task, 2. remove, then 3. enqueue again.

Comment: I think you should edit your question, cause it is not the first thing people might understand in the first place

Comment: @TUIlover Edit the question is very welcome and well appreciated! In fact, I don't know if the question was described clearly and how others understand it...

Comment: If you can't lock a lock, then there's no way to guarantee that the value returned by `len()` will be the length of the queue or, that the value returned by `peek()` will be the item at the head. Contrariwise, if you _do_ lock the queue while using the values returned by `len()` or `peek()`, then that pretty much kills the benefit of making any of the other operations non-blocking.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Why? if we have an atomic value to record length and a pointer that points to the head of the queue, it is easy to implement them by atomic operations, right?

Comment: You can write a `peek()` function that guarantees that the item it returns _was_ at the head of the queue at some instant during the call, but another thread could cause a different item to become the head before the `peek()` call returns. Same goes for the `len()` function. Maybe in some particular application you could make use of that imperfect information, but that would be a special case. In the _general_ case, you have to be able to block other threads from accessing the queue in order for `peek()` and `len()` to be meaningful.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, `peek` and `len` returns was the head and the former length, no problem. Should we say same idea for any `Load` atomic operation? Of course not. Peek and Len are not the main focus of the problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow `Peek` and `Len` are `Load`-like atomic operations. But, `Push`, `Pop` and `Update` are non-trivial and they require to manipulate a data structure rather than `int` or `void*`

Comment: @Jakob, You're missing my point. Sure, peek() and len() can be _implemented_ as non-blocking, atomic operations, but just because you can do that doesn't make them useful. Many (most?) use-cases for peek() or len() on a shared queue make no sense unless other threads are _blocked_ from modifying the queue while the first thread does whatever with the value that was returned.

Comment: @SolomonSlow OK that sounds fair. Now let's say we only need `push()` `pop()` and `update()` three operation to be lockless. How could we implement it?

Comment: I would try to avoid the requirement for update().  For task scheduling, for example, you can just add a new entry when the priority is raised, and invalidate the previous one.  When the priority is lowered you leave the priority queue alone and reschedule the task when it's executed.

Comment: @MattTimmermans How could we achieve `invalidate the previous one`? This arises a search problem.

Comment: @Jakob if it's a task queue, then you just mark the task as "already started".  If you have multiple entries in the queue that all point to the same task, then the same task could be popped off several times. After popping, though, if you can't CAS it the task state from "Not started yet" to "started", then forget about it and pop another one, so the task will only run once.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Sorry, but I still don't get how could we "mark the task as already started"? We have to find the task then mark the task as already started. Literature also doesn't support `find()` by a given key.

Comment: @Jakob imagine you had the `update` function that you want.  What would its parameters be?

Comment: @MattTimmermans well, if a task is associated with a unique id, then the the update op would be: update(char* task_id, time_t new_priority)

Comment: @Jakob  That's a little odd, but OK.  So when you wanted to run the task you would go to some different data structure and say `Task *t = tasks.getById(task_id)` or something like that.  Then `if (t->markInProgress()) t->run()` or something like that.  I.e., this marking has nothing to do with the priority queue at all.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you for your patient. I am trying to follow your thoughts and giving a try to implement it. What I am still confusing is, what is the data structure for `tasks`? are we managing tasks by a linear storage `tasks` and a linear queue only for priority records? if so, how could we guarantee CAS operation being consistency when we manipulating two data structure?

Comment: @Jakob If you're using C++, then I would have the priority queue records contain `int priority` and `shared_ptr<Task> task`.  Multiple priority records for the same task would be OK.  You should use task pointers (smart or otherwise) to identify tasks in your application, since that's what pointers are for.  If you also need to find tasks by ID then you can have an additional `std::map<string,shared_ptr<Task>>` or similar for that purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure a lockless concurrent binary heap even exists. I do know that it's a lot easier to create a lock-free priority queue based on a skip list than a binary heap. I suspect that you could do something similar with a pairing heap. But a lock-free binary heap? I've seen low-lock implementations, but don't recall seeing a no-lock variant.